# How to build inverse relationship to Entity which has more than two relationship to it?

Tags: entity-framework, core-data

I have an entities Group and Person with relationships:

```
Group:

Group.leader ->  Person (To One)
Group.looser ->  Person (To One)
Group.others ->> Person (To Many)
```

In `leader`, `looser` and `others` set I could have different `Person` entities. Same Person could be `leader` in one group, `looser` in second and appears in `others` set in third group.

in `Person` entity I have To-Many relationship `groups` which should connect

```
Person:

Person.groups ->> Group (should be enough but warnings)
```

Because I can make only one inverse relationship I always
 will have a warning "*something* should have inverse"

How to deal with relationships like this?

Or:
I have entities `Cube`, `Plan` and `Line`. `Cube` has relationships `x`, `y`, `z`, Plane `x` and `y`, Line just `x`. And I need to share some values between them, even sometimes mixed:

```
Cube:
Cube.x --> Value
Cube.y --> Value
Cube.z --> Value

Plane:
Cube.x --> Value
Cube.y --> Value

Line:
Cube.x --> Value

Value:
Value.counted -->> Line.x or Line.y, Plane.x, Cube.x, y, z, SomeAnotherEntity.neededValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple recommend that every relationship should have an inverse.  In your case, that would mean the `Person` entity would have three relationships:

```
Person.groupsLed ->> Group (to many) // "groups where this Person is leader"
Person.groupsLost ->> Group (to many) // "groups where this person is the looser"
Person.otherGroups ->> Group (to many) // "other groups with this person as a member"
```

which does seem rather complicated.  One alternative would be to collapse the three relationships into one (for each of `Person` and `Group`) with an intermediate entity (`Ranking`?):

```
Group.rankings ->> Ranking (to many) // "the ranking of people for this group"
Person.rankings ->> Ranking (to many) // "the ranking of this person in different groups"
```

In each case the inverse would be to-one:

```
Ranking.person -> (Person) (to one) // "the person for this ranking"
Ranking.group -> (Group) (to one) // "the group for this ranking"
```

You can then add an attribute to the `Ranking` entity to indicate the leaders/loosers/other.  That could be a simple string attribute `rank` which takes the values "leader", "looser" or "other", or an equivalent integer enum.  To manage the relationship between a `Group` and a `Person`, you add or remove `Ranking` objects.  One downside to all this is that finding the leader or looser involves filtering the rankings, but it does give you a degree of flexibility.

Comment: It's really great answer. But it's very hard to control logic and possible errors. I will try. Thank You!

Comment: But what to do in much simpler case: let say I have an entity Position, which has relationships x and y one-to-one to entity Value. I can connect back  Value one-to-many to Position but... warnings of course. In a worse case I would like to use some of Values not only for Position, but for Color (three of them) or Distance (only one)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - could you update your question to provide more detail?