# How can I model a binary tree in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I currently have an Entity that has two relationships: `leftChild` and `rightChild`:

```
Node:
    leftChild: Node (no inverse)
    rightChild: Node (no inverse)
```

Now I want each node to have a `parent`, and set that as the inverse for both childs too:

```
Node:
    leftChild: Node (`parent` is inverse)
    rightChild: Node (`parent` is inverse)
    parent: Node
```

The problem is, Core Data doesn't seem to like having `parent` as the inverse for two relationships. But of course both leftChild and rightChild will have the same parent. So I'm ending up with this unsatisfying result:

```
Node:
    leftChild: Node (`leftParent` is inverse)
    rightChild: Node (`rightParent` is inverse)
    leftParent: Node
    rightParent: Node
```

but "leftParent" and "rightParent" don't make sense since there's just one parent. Is there a better way to model this?

Comment: Does your model break if you add a sense of sidedness (left/right) to your Node because a one to many relationship from parent to child will handle the split and from there left or right node is a filter away.

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding @WarrenBurton, you're saying instead of leftChild and rightChild, I should just have `children` that is an array of children, and assume that array only has 2 children?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4985075/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46686694/1187415.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model your relationship from the parent to children as `to-many` and from child to parent as `to-one`

[image]
[image]

If your node carries a sense of sidedness e.g `isLeft: Bool` then the left and right node can be yielded by filter or predicate.

```
extension Node {
    var leftNode: Node? {
        return (children as? Set<Node>)?
            .filter({ $0.isLeft })
            .first
    }

    var rightNode: Node? {
        return (children as? Set<Node>)?
            .filter({ !$0.isLeft })
            .first
    }
}
```

The other suggestions like using an ordered set for the `to-many`  relationship could also work better for your use case.